# Can't hear anything through the speakers

Tags: pulseaudio, skype, alsa

I was going to have a skype call but I was unable to hear anything.
Everything was working fine until now.
Moreover, when I checked..I could not hear any songs, videos or any videos from youtube.

Did some search and executed these commands :

```
sudo gpasswd -a akshay audio
```

After this, I executed -

```
killall pulseaudio
```

But still I cannot hear anything.

Any ideas ?

`pulseaudio --check` didn't work, displayed nothing.

Here are the results for `pulseaudio --dump-conf`:

```
akshay@akshay-Inspiron-5521:~$ pulseaudio --dump-conf
### Read from configuration file: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ###
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib/pulse-3.0/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = auto
log-level = notice
resample-method = speex-float-1
enable-remixing = yes
enable-lfe-remixing = no
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 10
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 1000000
```

Comment: @Braiam
Update it mate.

Comment: @Braiam,
Gives me this error :-
akshay@akshay-Inspiron-5521:~$ amixer -c 1 -- sset Master playback 0dB
Invalid card number.

I even tried including pacmd dump-volumes..but I got the same error.

Comment: @Braiam,
Sweet! atleast I can hear something.
But, it's too scratchy..if I increase the volume..it gets more scratchy...I had windows few days ago and the sound was pretty decent...anything I can do on linux to make the sound more powerful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your volume was in 0 which prevented you from hearing anything:

```
$ amixer -c 0 -- sget Master
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-64.00dB] [on]
```

You have two options, using `alsamixer` which is in the `alsa-utils` package:

```
 sudo apt-get -y install alsa-utils && alsamixer
```

And use the nice curses to modify your volume, or doing directly with `amixer` as pointed out in comments:

```
amixer -c 0 -- sset Master 100%
```

Using decibels is valid too:

```
amixer -c 0 -- sset Master -24dB
```

Then check your system volume manager to check that the volume is correct and rock your world!

Comment: Perfect, everything running smoothly and sweetly.
Thanks.